# What is a Check Word?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Check Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Check Words™ | Not Check Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| CRY | SMILE |
| BMW | MERCEDES |
| THOSE | THEM |
| CRLF | NEWLINE |
| STOUT | LAGER |
| DONUT | BAGEL |
| HOUND | DOG |
| SHADE | SHADY |

**Update / Hint:**

> Check Words™ are so-named because of a certain person of "Check" heritage.

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Check Words™,Not Check Words™
CRY,SMILE
BMW,MERCEDES
THOSE,THEM
CRLF,NEWLINE
STOUT,LAGER
DONUT,BAGEL
HOUND,DOG
SHADE,SHADY
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think a Check Word is a word that

> can be typed on only one row of the Dvorak keyboard layout.

They are called Check Words because

> Check sounds like Czech, which is the nationality of the composer Dvorak